# Get the last n digits of a long

Tags: python, python-3.x

My program asks user to enter a power and how many digits they want. And finds the last that many digits of 2 raised to the power the user entered.

My code looks like this. I am just a beginner in python. I am not getting the output desired.

```
temp = int(input('Enter the power of the number: '))
temp2 = int(input('Enter the no.of digits you want: '))
temp3 = (2 ** temp) // temp2
temp4 = (temp3 % 100)
print('The last that many digits of the number raised to the power is is:',temp4)
```

Comment: You want to use explicit variable names. `temp, temp2, temp4` should be `power, digits, last_digits` for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming you are looking for something like this:

power: 8

digits: 2

2 ^ 8 = 256

last two digits = 56

To do this your code would look like this:

```
power = int(input('two to the power of '))
digits = int(input('last how many digits? '))

num = 2 ** power # calculate power
num = num % (10 ** digits) # get remainder of division by power of 10
print(num)
```

Here's another approach:

```
power = int(input('two to the power of '))
digits = int(input('last how many digits? '))

num = 2 ** power # calculate power
num = str(num) # convert with string to work with
num = num[-digits:] # get last n digits
num = int(num)
print(num)
```

Comment: I don't need the string though.

Comment: Then you could use int(num) to convert it back to an interger after getting the last few digits

Comment: Converting to and from a string and slicing is probably way less efficient than just doing the math.Your 2nd solution is best

Comment: Its not working. I am not getting the desired output by those two methods. For example, 2^8 = 256 and I want 56 as output, I am getting '25' by using the method without string conversion.And I am getting '2' as output by using the int to string conversion method.

Comment: Hi, I just realized I made two mistakes, just fixed them though and it should work